# Combining rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with an index called `city_id` of cities in the format `[city],[state]` (e.g., `new york,ny` containing integer counts in the columns. The problem is that I have multiple rows for the same city, and I want to collapse the rows sharing a `city_id` by adding their column values. I looked at `groupby()` but it wasn't immediately obvious how to apply it to this problem.

Edit:

An example: I'd like to change this:

```
city_id    val1 val2 val3
houston,tx    1    2    0
houston,tx    0    0    1
houston,tx    2    1    1
```

into this:

```
city_id    val1 val2 val3
houston,tx    3    3    2
```

if there are ~10-20k rows.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate and @DSM's answer `df.groupby(df.index)` doesn't appear in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Starting from

```
>>> df
              val1  val2  val3
city_id                       
houston,tx       1     2     0
houston,tx       0     0     1
houston,tx       2     1     1
somewhere,ew     4     3     7
```

I might do

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index).sum()
              val1  val2  val3
city_id                       
houston,tx       3     3     2
somewhere,ew     4     3     7
```

or

```
>>> df.reset_index().groupby("city_id").sum()
              val1  val2  val3
city_id                       
houston,tx       3     3     2
somewhere,ew     4     3     7
```

The first approach passes the index values (in this case, the `city_id` values) to `groupby` and tells it to use those as the group keys, and the second resets the index and then selects the `city_id` column.  See [this section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#aggregation) of the docs for more examples.  Note that there are lots of other methods in the `DataFrameGroupBy` objects, too:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index)
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1045a1790>
>>> df.groupby(df.index).max()
              val1  val2  val3
city_id                       
houston,tx       2     2     1
somewhere,ew     4     3     7
>>> df.groupby(df.index).mean()
              val1  val2      val3
city_id                           
houston,tx       1     1  0.666667
somewhere,ew     4     3  7.000000
```

Comment: Is there anyway to select the row which has the maximum mean in its group? In this example, it should select `houston,tx       2     1     1` from the first group.

Comment: Is there a method where you might define a column to sum, another to max, another to min so the result would be Huston, TX 3 (sum), 2 (max), 1(min)?

Answer (score 5):

Something in the same line. Sorry not the exact replica.

```
mydata = [{'subid' : 'B14-111', 'age': 75, 'fdg':1.78},
          {'subid' : 'B14-112', 'age': 22, 'fdg':1.56},{'subid' : 'B14-112', 'age': 40, 'fdg':2.00},]
df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)

gg = df.groupby("subid",sort=True).sum()
```