# Remove duplicate rows from DataFrame but keeping one column as list- Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
file:
      | FIRST | LAST | ID |
---------------------------
0      "ABC"     12    35 
1      "ABC"     14    35
2      "AB"      15    36
```

Now, what I want is:

```
file:
      | FIRST | LAST  | ID |
---------------------------
0      "ABC"   [12,14]  35 
2      "AB"      15     36
```

For this problem let's assume that if **ID** of two rows is equal then all the values except **LAST** is also equal.

Therefore, replace all the value except the values of last, which are added to a list.

I tried using solution given in this link:
[Pandas DataFrame - Combining one column's values with same index into list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796973/pandas-dataframe-combining-one-columns-values-with-same-index-into-list)

I used this:

```
file = file.groupby('ID')

file = file['Last'].unique()
```

This is the output I got:

```
ID
35    [12, 14]
36        [15]
Name: Last, dtype: object
```

Probably, I am missing something in the groupby().

Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:**

My original Dataframe has more than 100 columns.
if **ID** of two rows is equal then all the values except **LAST** is also equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that only the last two rows are different for a given ID, just take the first value when applying a groupby to them.  For the column `LAST', use its value or convert it to a list of unique items if there are more than one.

```
grouping_cols = ['ID', ...]
agg_cols = {col: 'first' for col in df if col not in grouping_cols}
agg_cols['LAST'] = lambda x: x.unique().tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x.iat[0]
>>> df.groupby(grouping_cols, as_index=False).agg(agg_cols)
  ID      LAST FIRST
0  35  [12, 14]   ABC
1  36        15    AB
```

Comment: what if i want to groupby() using multiple columns?

Comment: This is what i got: **ValueError: function does not reduce**

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
df.groupby(['FIRST', 'ID']).LAST.apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()

    FIRST   ID  LAST
0   AB      36  [15]
1   ABC     35  [12, 14]
```

Comment: My Dataframe has more than 100 columns so when I put ['First','ID'] in groupby, all the other columns won't be there.

Comment: In that case, even the other columns would need to be aggregated, do you want them in list as well?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, if value of ID is equal for two rows then all the other column values are also equal, except LAST.