# Join rows dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

| title | number |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 3 |
| edf | 4 |
| abc | 2 |
| edf | 1 |

How can I produce this output?
The data is grouped by `title` column.

| title | number |
| --- | --- |
| abc | [3, 2] |
| edf | [4, 1] |

To create the same dataframe I use you can use the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "title": ['abc', 'edf', 'abc', 'edf'],
    "number": [3, 4, 2, 1],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438906/combining-rows-in-pandas

Comment: `df.groupby('title')['number'].agg(list)`

Comment: kindly post it as an answer @ScottBoston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `aggregation`. It makes data from different rows but with same `title` column value gets together. Then you create a list of all items.

`df` is your initial dataframe object.

```
df.groupby("title", as_index=False).aggregate(lambda item: [i for i in item])
```

This code do this: First group by `title` column. So `3` and `2` would be together as they have the same `title` column value. And the same happens for the other values.

Then with `aggregate` method we tell python to put all the values that are together in a list.

So the final result would like this:

| title | number |
| --- | --- |
| abc | [3, 2] |
| edf | [4, 1] |